How to always pull the latest Memgraph docker image when using Docker compose?
I've seen last week that Memgraph 2.16 was released. I use the following docker-compose.yml file:
version: "3"

services:
  memgraph:
    image: memgraph/memgraph-mage:latest
    container_name: memgraph-mage
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
      - "7444:7444"
    command: ["--log-level=TRACE"]

  lab:
    image: memgraph/lab:latest
    container_name: memgraph-lab
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - memgraph
    environment:
      - QUICK_CONNECT_MG_HOST=memgraph
      - QUICK_CONNECT_MG_PORT=7687

When I run it, I get the Memgraph 2.15.2, and not 2.16.
I noticed that I have a local docker image with 2.15.2 tag that is tagged as latest. I've deleted it, and now I get 2.16 when I run docker compose.
What can I add to my docker-compose.yml to always pull the latest from Docker hub? I'm looking for something that would be equivalent to docker run --pull=always.

You need to update your YAML file so that version is 3.4, and you need to set pull_policy: always. This way, when you run docker compose up latest tag will refere to the Docker hub version.
version: "3.4" 

services:
  memgraph:
    image: memgraph/memgraph-mage:latest
    container_name: memgraph-mage
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
      - "7444:7444"
    command: ["--log-level=TRACE"]
    pull_policy: always

  lab:
    image: memgraph/lab:latest
    container_name: memgraph-lab
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - memgraph
    environment:
      - QUICK_CONNECT_MG_HOST=memgraph
      - QUICK_CONNECT_MG_PORT=7687
    pull_policy: always


Specifying the exact version number 2.16 in the image property for the memgraph service.
memgraph:
    image: memgraph/memgraph-mage:2.16
    container_name: memgraph-mage

Docker Compose will always pull that specific version when you run docker-compose up.
